# Odoo hide some view type on specific model

Tags: odoo-13

I need the following view types on CRM  hide calendar,pivot,graph,cohort,dashboard using a custom module
I tried with this without success

```
<record id="crm_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">CRM views</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="view_type">crm.lead.kanban</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form,calendar,graph</field>
</record>
```

thanks

**UPDATE**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that you want to hide calendar, pivot, graph, cohort and dashboard views in that CRM action?

Comment: Yes, use only kanban, tree

Comment: Do you know how to get the XML ID of an action? Can you write me the XML ID of the CRM action you want to modify? For CRM, there are a bunch of them, and none of the main ones have those set of calendar, pivot, graph, cohort, dashboard views. If you give me XML ID I will post you a more accurate answer.

Comment: Here is your answer https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/hidden-kanban-view-sales-customers-134482

Comment: I have update the answer, i found it on Technical settings -> Actions on window is it i don't know if it this correct

Comment: Enough to see the the XML ID (field *ID esterno* in Italian). I have posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your module should depend on `crm`. Then, the code must be this:

```
<record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="crm.crm_lead_action_pipeline">
    <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
</record>
```